# FitNesse Tests stopped working because of malformed request string

Tags: c#, fitnesse, httpexception

I am setting up FitNesse Acceptance tests for a SignalR hub application. The tests were executing and succeeding earlier this week.

Now I am getting an exception in the FitNesse execution window:

```
WARNING: An error occured while fulfilling user request [fitnesse.http.HttpExcep
tion: The request string is malformed and can not be parsed]
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: fitnesse.http.HttpException: The reques
t string is malformed and can not be parsed
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
        at fitnesse.FitNesseExpediter.makeResponse(FitNesseExpediter.java:107)
        at fitnesse.FitNesseExpediter.run(FitNesseExpediter.java:60)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: fitnesse.http.HttpException: The request string is malformed and can
not be parsed
        at fitnesse.http.Request.checkRequestLine(Request.java:159)
        at fitnesse.http.Request.readAndParseRequestLine(Request.java:73)
        at fitnesse.http.Request.parse(Request.java:61)
        at fitnesse.FitNesseExpediter$1.call(FitNesseExpediter.java:104)
        at fitnesse.FitNesseExpediter$1.call(FitNesseExpediter.java:101)
        ... 4 more
```

In the wiki browser it shows as:

```
Testing was interrupted and results are incomplete. Test Pages: 0 right, 0 wrong, 0 ignored, 0 exceptions     Assertions: 0 right, 0 wrong, 0 ignored, 0 exceptions (21.689 seconds)
Could not complete testing: java.lang.Exception: FitClient: external process terminated before a connection could be established.
```

The tests run C# applications that subscribe to events on SignalR, post changes through a Rest API and verify that the expected messages are received.

I tried updating the Rest API and the Push API. I updated the FitNesse software to the latest version.

I am not getting any exceptions in the Windows Event Log when this happens.

Can anyone guide me as to how to find out what is going wrong?

Comment: Does it happen on each test execution? I've had a similar message at irregular intervals, but was unable to reproduce it consistently. So usually running the test again worked (did not show the error).

Comment: I am starting to think it was something to do with networking. It was still working at work. Since I took the laptop home, it did not execute any (local) test and always fails with the errors mentioned.

Comment: Maybe you can use your browsers dev tools to see network requests sent to fitnesse. it sounds like some Ajax gone bad. Have you tried restarting fitnesse?

Comment: My suspicion is confirmed. Back at work, the FitNesse Test start to work again. I take that as a sign that I should not have taken my work home. ;-) @Fied Hoeben: I tried many things including restarting FitNesse, restarting IIS, publishing my services countless times, restarting my PC.

Comment: Try this technique to see if the C# code is throwing an unexpected exception: http://www.asoftwarecraft.com/2010/01/troubleshooting-with-fitsharp-and.html